# javax.jms.JMSException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, rabbitmq, qpid

I am a newbie who is trying to integrate **qpid** with **Apache Camel**. I need to write java code to read and write from a queue using **qpid**.

So firstly I downloaded the JMS example from qpid website. The code that I am trying to run is.

```
/*
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 *
 */
package org.apache.qpid.jms.example;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.DeliveryMode;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.ExceptionListener;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            // The configuration for the Qpid InitialContextFactory has been supplied in
            // a jndi.properties file in the classpath, which results in it being picked
            // up automatically by the InitialContext constructor.
            Context context = new InitialContext();

            ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("myFactoryLookup");
            Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("myQueueLookup");

            Connection connection = factory.createConnection(System.getProperty("USER"), System.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
            connection.setExceptionListener(new MyExceptionListener());
            connection.start();

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
            MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("Hello world!");
            messageProducer.send(message, DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, Message.DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE);
            TextMessage receivedMessage = (TextMessage) messageConsumer.receive(2000L);

            if (receivedMessage != null) {
                System.out.println(receivedMessage.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No message received within the given timeout!");
            }

            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception, exiting.");
            exp.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static class MyExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {
        @Override
        public void onException(JMSException exception) {
            System.out.println("Connection ExceptionListener fired, exiting.");
            exception.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is dependent on the file ::

```
# Set the InitialContextFactory class to use
java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory
# Define the required ConnectionFactory instances
# connectionfactory.<JNDI-lookup-name> = <URI>
connectionfactory.myFactoryLookup = amqp://localhost:5672

# Configure the necessary Queue and Topic objects
# queue.<JNDI-lookup-name> = <queue-name>
# topic.<JNDI-lookup-name> = <topic-name>
queue.myQueueLookup = queue
topic.myTopicLookup = topic
```

Now I understand that inorder for this to work, I need something known as a Broker service. Doing some research, I found out that I can use RabbitMQ for this purpose. So I downloaded it on my Windows machine and am trying to connect to it on port `localhost:5672`

But when I run my code, I get the ERROR ::

```
2017-05-04 11:28:29,329 [main           ] - ERROR JmsConnection                  - Failed to connect to remote at: amqp://localhost:5672
Caught exception, exiting.
javax.jms.JMSException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:86)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.connect(JmsConnection.java:172)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactory.java:204)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.example.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why does this ERROR occur ? Whereas this port is definitely listening on my local machine. Again I am a newbie with JMS so any guidance will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Is your server running?

Comment: Yes. I did a `telnet 127.0.0.1 5672` and it works.

Comment: Not sure it's the case for your version of qpid but there seems to be a [bug in qpid 0.6 release preventing proper negotiation of protocol version](https://www.rabbitmq.com/interoperability.html), here is the statement: `The 0.6 release of the Qpid java client was shipped with a bug that prevents it from correctly negotiating the protocol version. As it defaults to AMQP 0-10, it is unable to connect to any 0-8 or 0-9-1 broker (including RabbitMQ).`

Comment: The Qpid 0.6 release referred to is of an older JMS client supporting the AMQP 0-X protocols, such as 0-9-1 mainly used with RabbitMQ. The new AMQP 1.0 based JMS client is what is being tried here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim mentioned, you would at minimum also have needed to ensure the brokers experimental AMQP 1.0 plugin was loaded, which you dont mention doing.

However, in this case it might not make much difference. I didn't have much success using the JMS client or some other AMQP 1.0 clients against RabbitMQ previously due to an issue I reported which stops them in their tracks when creating consumers and producers: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0/issues/34

Your mentioned researching things deciding to use RabbitMQ, which sounds like you aren't tied to an existing server solution? If so, for other servers that support AMQP 1.0 and the JMS client is routinely used against, you could try ActiveMQ, ActiveMQ Artemis, Qpid for Java broker, Qpid C++ broker, or Qpid Dispatch router (doesn't work on Windows, which you mention using), amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be using the [Qpid JMS AMQP v1.0 client](http://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html) which will not be able to connect to RabbitMQ unless you are using the experimental AMQP 1.0 plugin for RabbitMQ.

Make sure you are using a client that is compatible with the broker you are running.